# (Xubuntu) prompts me for authentication so it can suspend the computer

Tags: xubuntu, suspend, authentication

I left Xubuntu idle for the amount of time needed for it to suspend automatically (and it locks the screen too). When coming back, **I typed my password** and there was another **box floating on the desktop asking for authentication** to allow the system to suspend!

I'm assuming my computer is not suspending because **it's asking permission to suspend!** That's crazy. I wanna know why it's happening and how to deal with it. I have to type my password twice: first to unlock the screen and then again to allow it to suspend (which appearently didn't happen before and won't happen from there. I just continue to use my laptop).

Please help me track this issue down.